# limit number of xAxis in a highchart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I'm using highCharts with angularJs and I want to limit the number of xAxis to 5; so the highchart shows only 5 xAxis there is my code:

```
 title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      tickPixelInterval: 50
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
```

[image]

Comment: "shows only 5 xAxis" what do you mean? As in only 5 ticks on the xAxis?

Comment: yes this is what I want

Comment: using '[tickPositions'](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositions) is one way to do it. I don't know if there is any other method. Yo have to tell highcharts where you want the ticks to be placed. 5 elements in the array passed to 'tickPositions' would mean 5 ticks.

Comment: Apart of tickPositions, you can use [tickAmount](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickAmount) or [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner)

Answer (score 0):

tickAmount cannot be used with Datetime, logarithmic or category axes as mentioned [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickAmount).

tickPositions can be used to achieve this.

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  categories: ['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03', '2016-02-01', '2016-02-02', '2016-03-01', '2016-03-02', '2016-04-01', '2016-04-02'],
  tickPositions: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
}
```

The values in the tickPositions array are the index positions.
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s190ebby/39/).